# Image Alignment within a Grid

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I would like to style these images by placing them in a CSS grid. Within CSS, I have created two columns and two rows for these four images to be placed in a grid which I believed would work.

Secondly, I wanted the images to have the same width and height as each other therefore I applied *width = "800" height="800"* to each image on the html only. But by doing so, the images were different for each viewport which I did not want and would remove responsiveness which I want.

```css
.about-images{
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-template-rows: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 1.5rem;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="the-life-of-a-chef">
        <div class="rest-info">
                <div class="restdsc pad-right animate-right">
                    <div class="LifeOfChefHeadline">
                        <h2 class="AboutHeadline">
                            <span class="About">About</span>
                        </h2>
                        <h1 class="headline headline-gold">The Life Of A Chef</h1>
                    </div>
                    <p>
                        The life of a chef is about Mauris eu tincidunt ipsum. 
                        Proin eleifend in orci et scelerisque. 
                        Mauris vitae turpis magna. Aenean ligula nunc, pretium eu sem vitae, ornare sodales odio. 
                        Nunc ut erat libero. Donec posuere et dui sed lobortis. 
                        Suspendisse id nibh ut tellus dictum ornare. Donec quis aliquam quam. 
                        Nam et urna id neque molestie iaculis. 
                    </p>
                    <a href="#" class="button contact-button">Contact</a>
                </div>
                <div class="about-images animate-right">
                    <img src="SiuLungBao.webp" width="800 height=800">
                    <img src="Skewer.webp" width="800" height="800">
                    <img src="NoodleChef.webp" width="800" height="800">
                    <img src="SushiMaking.webp" width="800" height="800">
                </div>
            </div>
        
    </section>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey, it looks like you forgot to put a semi-colon at the end of your `grid-template-rows`.

Also, where did you add the width and height to your HTML? I can't find it.

Comment: Also, can you clarify your goal? Maybe include an image of how you'd like your website to be?

Comment: @kvncnls Edits made. https://www.siteinspire.com/websites/6211-blid - What I would like my website too look like.

Comment: Try `max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;`